# SQL WHERE CURDATE

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to complete, which i thought would be simple, a `where` statement within SQL using `CurDate` instead of me having to amend dates each time i run my code, i am looking for the `where` statement to look over a 360 period, beginning today and working backwards.

I have tried all of the items below and neither will work, please can someone tell me where i am going wrong.

```
Where LastPD > CurDate()- interval 360 days;
Where LastPD > CurDate()-360;
Where LastPD > CurDate-360;
```

I am trying to reduce a file with over 20 million rows of data to show data with either a `LastPD` within the last 6/12 months or a `AssignDate` within the last 6/12 Months.

The code i have previously used is as follows;

```
Data DCARMSLive12LPD;
Set DCARMSLive12;
Where LastPD > '20170320';
run;
Data DCARMSLive12PLC;
Set DCARMSLive12;
Where AssignDate > '20MAr2017'd;
Run;
Data DCARMSLive06LPD;
Set DCARMSLive6;
Where LastPD > '20170920';
run;
Data DCARMSLive06PLC;
Set DCARMSLive6;
Where AssignDate > '20Sep2017'd;
Run;
```

I want to replace the actual date within the where statements so they do not have to be updated manually each time the code is ran.

Comment: How about GetDate(),

Comment: Could you be clearer on which RDBMs product you are using, SQL is a language with variations per database - especially around date handling / manipulation commands

Comment: So what happens with your attempts? Do you get *error messages*? (If so, what?). Or do you get wrong results? (If so, how are you identifying that the results are "wrong"?) Or something else (if so, what?)

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Please add the tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: If the first two do not work, then you are not using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE LastPD > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY);
```

Comment: The full code is  as follows and is being used in SAS EG 4.3                                                         
Data DCARMSLive12LPD;
Set DCARMSLive12;
WHERE LastPD > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY);
run;

Comment: the error message is as follows;                                               
 WHERE LastPD > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY);
                                                       ___
                                                       22
                                                       76
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, (, ), *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, 
              BETWEEN, CONTAINS, EQ, GE, GT, IN, IS, LE, LIKE, LT, NE, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.

Comment: what is the data type of column `lastPd`?

Comment: LastPD is Type:Character & Format: $8. and the previous working step was /*Where LastPD > '20170320';*/   I am also trying to complete this on Assign date which is Type:Numeric and Format DATE9. with the previous working step being /*Where AssignDate > '20MAr2017'd;*/

Comment: Share the full details with more clarification since I am not getting where you are failing. Try to add some sample data with the expected result.

Comment: I have amended the main query to hopefully provide further clarity

Comment: Can you tell me which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness as i am new and learning SAS/SQL etc.

Comment: I think it is Teradata based on code which is auto ran each morning - %let rdbms=teradata;

Comment: `DATE_SUB` is proprietary syntax, Standard SQL uses `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '360' DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Teradata uses Standard SQL

```
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '360' DAY
```

or shorter (non-Standard)

```
CURRENT_DATE -360
```

*Date Literals*  are Standard SQL, too:

```
DATE '2018-03-21'
```

Comment: Thanks, am i correct in saying that my code should therefore become:                                                                                             Data DCARMSLive12LPD;
Set DCARMSLive12;
where LastPD > CURRENT_DATE - 360;
run;

Comment: @KelvinW: As long as SAS submits that WHERE as-is, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,  i ended up solving the issue as follows as i could not get any of the above suggestions to work.

i added the current_date as a variable on the data, reformatted yymmdd8. to Date9. and used the following code

```
Where LPD > Current_Date -360;
```

or
    Where AssignDate > Current_Date -180;